# Why does the root pointer get initialized to null always?

Tags: c++, variable-initialization

I'm very confused about the following code:

```
class Tree {
protected:
    struct Node {
        Node* leftSibling;
        Node* rightSibling;
        int value;
    };  
private:
    Node* root;
    int value;
.....
public:
    void addElement(int number) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            printf("This is the value of the pointer %lld\n",(long long)root);
            printf("This is the value of the int %d\n",value);
            ...
            return;
        }
        printf("NOT NULL\n");
    }
};


int main() {
    Tree curTree;
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0;i < 40; ++i) {
        curTree.addElement(rand() % 1000);
    }
}
```

The `curTree` variable is local to the main function so I expected it to not have its members initialized to 0, but they are both initialized.

Comment: Does the class have a user defined default constructor?

Comment: are you essentially asking why this works? `if (root == NULL)` and why root will end up being null?

Comment: The `value` you are printing is the argument to `addElement`, not the private member. Use `this->value` to print the attribute.

Comment: There is no user defined constructor. I'm asking why the values are initialized, because I thought they shouldn't be. Thanks to agbinfo for pointing out that very silly bug I had.

Comment: @user502248: Zero is a valid value for being uninitialized.

Comment: I would have guessed that the problem was a conflict, that you had a local variable "root" someplace and had initialized that instead of member root. Try prefixing your member variables with "m_", e.g. "m_root", to avoid running into that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it has **unspecified contents**.  Those contents might be random memory garbage, or they could just happen to be 0, depending on whatever data was left in their memory location beforehand.

It might just happen that due to the way the code was compiled, the particular stack location containing `root` always has 0 (say, because an earlier local variable occupying that same stack location always ended up as 0).  But you cannot rely on this behavior -- you must properly initialize anything before reading it back, otherwise you enter the land of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Reader's Digest version: you got lucky :)

Answer (score 2):

The actual default value a pointer is implicitly initialized to will depend on the compiler you use.
The Visual C compiler (v2012) will initialize it automatically to  __nullptr which is equal to NULL. Have a look [at the MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4ex65770.aspx) (see the last example).

I would try to check your compiler manual if you want more information.

Comment: Yeah this will depend on the compiler. Though i will say to write portable code .. u should define constructor and initalize the data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize `root` anywhere, proper place to initialize it would be the constructor.